# Where to store the global settings to allow the application to access them frequently without dropping a big over head on the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, database-connection, information-retrieval

I have some global settings in my application that is going to be handled by the administrator and I store them in the database.

Settings like: board on/off, max items/page on different UserControls, language, hide/show modules.

What technique should I follow to read the values in the database and display the page or the application according to it .. Of course I could do it the easy way and fetch the required settings for each page in the Page_Load event handler but I think that will be a lot of database connection!

Is there is any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to load your settings into the [Application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on `Application_Start` in your `global.asax`.

Comment: you can use ASPNet Runtime Cache (asp.net 4.0) or HttpCache(asp.net2.0/3.5) for that as well.

Comment: @Furqan. do you have newbie guide for Runtime Cache !?

Comment: @IKashef: Runtime Cache is an object introduced in System.Runtime.Caching Namespace, you can google it for more.

Comment: All the answers are about the same article "ASP.NET Runtime Cache - Clone Objects to Preserve Cached Data" !!